# Apache mutliple Access-Control-Allow-Origin settings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, centos, plesk

I have a bad Apache 2.4.6 config setting for a site on CentOS, set up with Plesk. Basically, one of my sites has multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin settings, and they're conflicting with each other. How do I check what all of the settings are for this value, and where they are being set?

I can't simply grep, since Plesk sets up multiple Apache conf files throughout the server. For example, some are in /etc/httpd/conf/, some in /etc/httpd/conf.d/, some in /var/www/vhosts/system/mydomain.com/conf/, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might find these two example commands usefull:

```
find /etc/httpd -type f -name "*.conf" -exec grep --color -Hni "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  {} \;

find /var/www/vhosts/system -type f -name "*.conf" -exec grep --color -Hni "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  {} \;
```